# Javascript query about context objects

Tags: javascript, closures

I have the following IFFE that creates a context object on the first call as

```
$_(document)
```

Result : obj {context: document}

However on the second call Im getting an error as

```
 $_(document)
```

Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function

As someone who is just getting familiar with the underlying concepts I want to know the reason for this behaviour

```
$_ = (function(){

    var obj = function (context){
        this.context = context
    }

    return function(context){
       return new obj(context)
    }
}())
```

Comment: I ran the above code in the chrome console. I think the braces are fine

Comment: For starters, `obj = ...` should be `var obj = ...` - otherwise there's no reason to use an IIFE if it's going to be in a global.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your TypeError.

Comment: Ur right. I changed it . But the error is not because of that

Comment: No errors in the Firefox console...

Comment: @TravisJ Did you try running it twice

Comment: $_ = (function(){

    obj = function (context){
        this.context = context
    }

    return function(context){
       return new obj(context)
    }
}())
var a = $_(document);
var b = $_(document);
console.log(a);
console.log(b);

Comment: That's mighty strange . I could upload a screenshot showing you the error when I do the same

Comment: There's no reason for this code to fail on subsequent calls.

Comment: I don't see an error either: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/thjw74xw/.  You've made the code a lot more complicated then necessary - see here for simplification: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/zeamy1ex/

Comment: Instead of trying to assign it to variables. Try 
Just executing 
$_(document) twice on the chrome console

Answer (score -1):

well , what we are doing here is. to return a function. with IFFE `typeof $_` is equal to "function", and when we send a context as a parameter, it construct a object with key-word new and return the object therefore it shows a object with a reference of object document